# static file locate issue on cpanel

Tags: django, django-urls, django-settings

my project is working fine on local but on live server(godaddy) its not getting static folder. urls are just

```
admin/
[name='homepage']
login/ [name='login']
^media\/(?P<path>.*)$
```

url for static not even located here .

my `settings.py` static settings are

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
```

**which are working on local perfectly** . and location for static folder is here in image , just a static folder placed. 
[image: image for directoy]

Comment: have you set DEBUG to False in production? If so then you're gonna have to setup Nginx or some other server to serve your static files. Cause Django is not very good at serving static files in general and should not be used to serve them in production.

Comment: well how did you upload your files in panel. Did you create a virutalevn?

Comment: @Sahil can you please refer to some link or solution please ?

Comment: @ngawang13 yes using terminal and cpanel.

Comment: I used pythonanywhere to host my project and i had the same issue. So i had to set the exact url location of the static file and run the collect static command and it worked. I dont know how you do it in godaddy. For what i think i think godaddy is not good for hosting django projects.

Comment: @gamer here's the official documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/deployment/#:~:text=Serving%20static%20files%20in%20production,static%20file%20server%20and%20served.

Comment: @ngawang13  yes seems this issue , but what will be settings in my case assuming my DNS name is    example.com ?

Comment: You can check the location of you static in ur terminal. Add that location in ur staticfile_root in ur setting.py. For example: home/yourdomainName/.../../static

Comment: @ngawang13    not working      STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")]
STATIC_ROOT = "/home/hmd2knu4x125/blogsite/static/"

Comment: Do you have anywhere in your Cpanal to add the static file location and did u you do python manage.py collectstatic

Comment: @ngawang13 I just placed code using github from terminal and after that ran  collectstatic

Comment: did it get all the staticfile without any error and just make sure that the staticroot location is correct and it should work. btw its not blogsite your folder is blog

Comment: @ngawang13   251 static files copied to '/home/hmd2knu4x125/blogsite/static'.
   I named folder on live as blogsite

Comment: Well, this is how to do in other Django hosting site. I have never use Cpanal soo it hard to say unless I see the whole process. I will do some research and get to you if i get any solution to it.

Comment: @ngawang13  got it worked , by using  STATIC_ROOT ="/home/hmd2knu4x125/public_html/static/"   .     But still dont know what is the reason :/

Comment: By default Cpanal store all the web file inside public_html folder. So I guess your static folder is inside it as well.

Comment: @ngawang13 yes maybe.thanks anyways bro

Answer (score 4, accepted):

got it worked , by using STATIC_ROOT ="/home/hmd2knu4x125/public_html/static/" .

By default Cpanal store all the web file inside public_html folder. So I guess static folder is inside it as well.   **hmd2knu4x125** was my instance name .

Comment: my config is STATIC_URL = '/assets/' so I have set STATIC_ROOT = "/home/[user_name]/public_html/assets" and it worked. thanks @gamer for the tip :)

Comment: Thank you! Your answer - the only one helped me after 2 days of googling